# Socketio client identify which room the message came from

Tags: node.js, socket.io

If a client joined multiple rooms and receives messages in those rooms is there a way for the client to identify which room his message came from (without incorporating the room in the message)?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a socket join a particular room, you can set property of that socket to that room like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var room = "yourRoomName";
  socket.on('join room', function(data){
    socket.join(room);
    socket.room = room;
  });
  socket.on('message', function(data){
    console.log('Received message '+data.message+' from room '+socket.room);
  })
});
```

**Client:**

```
socket.emit('join room', {your: 'data'});
socket.emit('message', {message: 'your message'});
```

Comment: Note in my question "(without incorporating the room in the message)".

Comment: Plus I don't think it is a good idea to tamper with the the socket itself. That is an object created by `socket.io`.

Comment: Then I don't think that it is possible. Let's suppose Client A has joined 3 rooms and Client B has joined 4 rooms. You can determine rooms a client has joined by io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]; So if Client B sends message to A then there doesn't seem a way to determine his room because it is in 4 rooms at a time. (Unless it is in a single room)

Comment: Also, socket.room = 'room' doesn't temper socket object because socket.io itself allows this.

Comment: Well... I cannot agree on your last comment, since you can define new functions on jquery as well, but it is not a good practice.

Comment: Sure you can disagree, but this is the flexibility of socket object. Same thing you can do with socket.set('room', 'chatRoom'); and get it like socket.get('room');